# Parse date and date-times in same column with lubridate and if_else()

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a character column in a dataframe that I want to parse as dates. The wrinkle is that it is a mixture of dates and date-times. The end goal is to have a column of dates only.

For example,

```
x = c("1995-01-01T00:00:00", "1/1/1985")
df = data_frame(d = x)
```

The first thing I thought to try was a simple `if_else`: parse with `ymd_hms()` if it is a date-time, if not parse with `mdy()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

datefun = function(x){
is_datetime = str_length(x) == 19
if_else(is_datetime, lubridate::date(lubridate::ymd_hms(x)),
lubridate::mdy(x))
}

df %>% mutate(parsed = datefun(d))
```

It works in the sense that it does return the desired column of class date, but lubridate also issues the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:

1:  1 failed to parse. 
2:  1 failed to parse.
```

It seems that the warning messages are coming about the lubridate functions are still trying to parse the entire vector of mixed dates and date-times. The solution I came up with was to modify `datefun` so that `ymd_hms` parses a vector of only date-times and `mdy` parses a vector of only `dates`.

```
datefun = function(x){
is_datetime = str_length(x) == 19
x_datetime = if_else(is_datetime, x, NA_character_)
x_date = if_else(!is_datetime, x, NA_character_)

if_else(is_datetime, lubridate::date(lubridate::ymd_hms(x_datetime)),
lubridate::mdy(x_date))
}
```

This seems to work i.e. I get the date-column without any warning messages, but it seems a little clunky. Am I missing a slicker and more intuitive way to do this?